# binomial coefficient algorithm using dynamic programming and a single dimensional array

Tags: java

I'm know a dynamic programming algorithm to compute the binomial coefficients with two-dimensional array like below . Is there any way to make use of one-dimensional array?

```
int binomialCoeff(int n, int k)
{
int C[n+1][k+1];
int i, j;


for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
 {
   for (j = 0; j <= min(i, k); j++)
    {

        if (j == 0 || j == i)
            C[i][j] = 1;


        else
            C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + C[i-1][j];
    }
    }

  return C[n][k];
  }
```

Comment: Welcome. It seems there is a problem with `{ and `}, and the first line of the code in not formatted as code.

Answer (score 2):

Your Dynamic Programming method (using 2D array) to solve Binomial Coefficient, seems correct. Note that we do not need to keep the whole table, only the prior row. So 1D implementation is possible!

Below is the code to implement it using a 1D array.

```
    int binomial_coefficient(int n, int k)
    {
          int C[k+1];int i,j;
          for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
                 C[i]=0;
          C[0]=1;
          for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
          {
                 for(j=min(i,k);j>0;j--)
                         C[j]=C[j]+C[j-1];
          }
          return C[k];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two dimensional arrays can be easily represented as one dimensional arrays.

instead of defining `C[n+1][k+1]`, define some `C2[(n+1)*(k+1)]`. Then, instead of calling `C[a][b]` call `C2[b*(n+1)+a]`.