# Calculate a term in Pascal's triangle iteratively

Tags: java, pascals-triangle, binomial-coefficients

I have the following method that needs to be implemented iteratively:

```
public int binom(int n, int k) {
        if (k < 0 || k > n) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (k == 0 || k == n) {
            return 1;
        }

        return binom(n - 1, k - 1) + binom(n - 1, k);
    }
```

The only condition is that I have to use the identity:

```
binom(n, k) = binom(n - 1, k - 1) + binom(n - 1, k)
```

I ended up with the following:

```
public int binom(int n, int k) {

    if (k < 0 || k > n) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (k == 0 || k == n) {
        return 1;
    }

    int[] previousRow = {1, 1};

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        int[] currentRow = new int[i+1];
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (j == 0 || j == i) {
                currentRow[j] = 1;
                continue;
            }

            currentRow[j] = previousRow[j-1] + previousRow[j];
        }
        previousRow = currentRow;
    }

    return previousRow[k - 1] + previousRow[k];
}
```

Is there a simpler/more obvious way to accomplish this that I'm missing?

Comment: This might be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Looks fine, but there are other ways.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36926193/2308683